# Error when trying to run composer install: "Use of undefined constant SeP"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm currently working in a laravel project and this error suddenly started to appear, anybody knows how to fix?

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                                                       
  Use of undefined constant SeP - assumed 'SeP' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)  
                                                                                                       

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel and PHP do you use? In which file exactly does this error occur? In a framework file? A package file? Your own file?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4. The error occurs in a framework file. The error appears when i try to run commands like ```composer install``` or ```php artisan migrate```.

Comment: This is an error in your own code or a package. There is nothing named `Repository` in laravel. Check line 208 of the file mentioned.

Comment: What have you tried to spot the problem? Why not run a full-text search over your code base?

Comment: @NicoHaase I did the search, i insert by accident the sentence 'SeP' instead of ```SectorPolicy::class``` on the AuthServiceProvider. That was the problem...

Comment: Just so someone knows. This is not a problem with our code. I am literally on a fresh build and am getting this problem. Looks like this is a laravel issue with it's current version. Pretty annoying really. I'm going to revert back to an older version from another server to make progress on this project I'm working on. Very disappointed with laravel.

Comment: @waltmagic, in my case it was a miss type in that class